# How to write data into an xls sheet in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, xls, fs

I am able to write data into an xls sheet but not in a proper mannaer ,pls see the pic below

[My xls sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drMYw.png)

My code,

```
var readString = '';
      readString = "Name"+"\t"+" From"+"\t"+" Created By"+"\t"+" Reminder Date"+"\t"+" Reminder Time"+"\n";
      event.forEach(function (v, i) {
        readString += v.attributes.task_name+"\t";
        readString += v.attributes.context_type+"\t";
        readString += v.created_by.employee.name+"\t";
        readString += v.attributes.reminder_date+"\t";
        readString += v.attributes.reminder_time+"\t";
        readString += "\n";
      });
      var currTime = new Date().getTime();
      var filePath = "./modules/upload/excel/task_" + currTime + ".xls";
      //studentInfo.filePath = "task_" + currTime + ".xls";
      var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
      writeStream.write(readString);
      writeStream.close();
```

Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `xlsx` npm package?

Comment: What you are creating is a TSV (tab-separated values) file. If you want to write xls, xlsx use a node module to do it. E.g. `json2xls`, `node-xlsx`, `xlsx`

Comment: You're writing it as a text. Excel files have a different header, style and formating info and many more things that you need to take care of. The easiest way is to use a node module that take care of all of that. Just search in npm website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To work with XLS files, see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xls
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx
- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/xls

But looking at your code you seem to be working with TSV data and not XLS. See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsv
- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/csv
- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/tsv

Note that TSV is the same as CSV with the only difference being the delimiter.